# Jenkins Twilio plugin - is there a way to configure text sending rules?

Tags: jenkins, twilio

I am currently using jenkins + twilio plugin.
Is there a way to configure the text message to send only for 3rd job failure?
and not for fixed build?

Thanks in advance,

Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I haven't used Jenkins for a long time and I've never created a plugin. However, I looked up the [Jenkins Twilio plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Twilio+Notifier+Plugin) and read the documentation. There doesn't seem to be the feature you're requesting here.

I did, however, note that the plugin has a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/twilio-notifier-plugin). So, you could either get in contact with the maintainer of the plugin (contact details also available on the [plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Twilio+Notifier+Plugin)) to request the feature or try to build it yourself. A quick glance through the source code lead me to [this method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/twilio-notifier-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/jenkins/TwilioNotifier.java#L444-L452) which returns whether the plugin should notify on this build.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try to add it myself, and also check with the developer.

Comment: No problem. Good luck getting the feature in!